# angular phonegap back button goes too deeply

Tags: angularjs, back-button, phonegap

I wrote a phonegap app with the following angular js routes

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        templateUrl:"views/index.html" /*global menu*/
    })
    .when("/home", {
        templateUrl:"views/home.html" /*item categories*/
    })
    .when('/listing',{
        templateUrl: 'views/listing.html' /*items in selected category*/
    })
    .when('/item',{
        templateUrl: 'views/item.html' /*single item page*/
    })
    .when('/about',{
        templateUrl: 'views/about.html' /*about us*/
    })
    .when('/settings',{
        templateUrl: 'views/settings.html' /*user settings/defaults */
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
    });
});
```

when I navigate through different views back and forth and click back button it comes in reverse order on all view I have visited, it looks awkward.
Instead it should come back till index (/) and if I tap back button being at index (/) the application should exit instead of going through whole history.
I tried the following code but not getting correct functionality

```
var h=[];  //history array
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, newUrl, oldUrl){ 
    if(h.length>0 && h[h.length -2] == newUrl){
        event.preventDefault();
        var currPath = oldUrl.substring(oldUrl.indexOf('#')+1);
        if(currPath=='/item'){
            $location.path('/listing');
        }else if(currPath=='/listing'){
            $location.path('/home');
        }else if(currPath=='/home' || currPath=='/about' || currPath=='/settings'){
            $location.path('/');
        }else if(currPath=='/'){
            navigator.app.exitApp();
        }
        h.pop();
    }else{
        h.push(newUrl); 
    }   
});
```

it is not going back correctly, some time behave like back even on taping some link, some time on back do not perform what is expected.
correct me with above back functionality or if there is some other alternative

the back button should work as

note `current_view` = current route before going back

`if current_view == '/item'`
    go to `/listing` route

`elseif current_view == '/listing'`
    go to `/home` route

`elseif current_view == '/home' || current_view == '/about' || current_view == '/settings'`
    go to `/` route

`elseif current_view == '/'`
    exit application

Comment: write a function which will redirect to your required page den you can simply call the that function on back button..

Comment: That's not the issue, problem is to detect backButton click